# Perl two identical strings compare as not equal

Tags: perl, string-comparison

Here is my code:

```
    my $self = shift;
    my $h    = shift;

    print "$h\n";

    my @headers = split /,/, $h;

    foreach my $el (@{$expected}) {
            my $t = shift @headers;
            chomp ($t);
            chomp ($el);
            print Dumper($el cmp $t, $el, $t);
            print "test: \'$el\' eq \'$t\' ";
            unless ($el eq $t) {
                    print "not ok $el ne $t\n";
                    return 0;
            } else {
                    print "ok\n";
            }
    }
    return 1;
```

In my first unit test I pass a string to $h which matches $expected.
I then have a unit test which ensure the function fails when passed a string that does not match.  These two tests behave as expected.

> Server,Jira Project,Issue Type,Summary,Description,Assignee,Labels,Epic Link
>
> $VAR1 = 0;
>
> $VAR2 = 'Server';
>
> $VAR3 = 'Server';
>
> test: 'Server' eq 'Server' ok

When I pull the line in from a CSV file and pass it to this function I get a different response.

> Server,Jira Project,Issue Type,Summary,Description,Assignee,Labels,Epic Link
>
> $VAR1 = -1;
>
> $VAR2 = 'Server';
>
> $VAR3 = 'Server';
>
> test: 'Server' eq 'Server' not ok Server ne Server

The compare somehow implies that the expected value is somehow less than what is being tested.  My mind immediately goes to there must be a leading or trailing character on what is being tested.  However, printing and Dumping doesn't seem to confirm that (unless I'm missing something).  The chomps are just out of sheer desperation.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you set `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` in your code before the call to `Dumper` and provide the updated output?

Comment: Most likely you have newlines (CR and/or LF) at the end of some data that you read from the CSV. Strip all whitespace from the end of the last item in that case.

Comment: @hobbs, great suggestion!  I've got some leading characters in there...

Answer (score 5):

First off thanks @hobbs for the $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; suggestion.  It was immediately obvious that there were some leading characters that I didn't know how to detect.

> $VAR1 = -1;
>
> $VAR2 = "Server";
>
> $VAR3 = "\357\273\277Server";

The CSV file I am reading contained [Byte Ordermarking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24096963/1542959) information.

I'll strip them off.  Thanks all for getting me going again.

Comment: If you use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) to read the CSV data (highly recommended), it will automatically deal with a BOM at the start of the header line.